# Inconsistent pool.map behavior

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm testing a really simple worker pool using python using this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import cycle

def do_stuff(work):
    core = work[0]
    inp = work[1]
    print('Running: "{}" "{}"'.format(core, inp))

def main():
    num_cores = 4
    jobs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
    with Pool(num_cores) as pool:
        work = list(zip(cycle(range(0, num_cores)), jobs))
        pool.map(do_stuff, work)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When the jobs array size is less than 16, it does what I expect it to do (Round Robin on the first column):

```
Running: "0" "a"
Running: "1" "b"
Running: "2" "c"
Running: "3" "d"
Running: "0" "e"
Running: "1" "f"
Running: "2" "g"
Running: "3" "h"
```

Here's the weird thing: When there's 16+ elements in the list, it starts distributing the job almost arbitrarily. E.g. for:

`jobs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']`

I get:

```
Running: "0" "a"
Running: "2" "c"
Running: "0" "e"
Running: "2" "g"
Running: "1" "b"
Running: "3" "d"
Running: "1" "f"
Running: "3" "h"
Running: "0" "i"
Running: "2" "k"
...
...
```

This completely messes up my setup. Any ideas why is this happening? Is there a way to enforce the distribution pattern `pool.map` uses?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The order the tasks are executed in? `pool.map` makes no guarantees about any such ordering.

Comment: First, you're not actually examining the distribution of work to cores at all. Second, it's not supposed to matter - if it does, `multiprocessing` isn't going to be enough. Third, you seem to want sequential execution, but that completely defeats the point of using multiprocessing or any sort of parallelism at all.

Answer (score -2):

Ah! I figured it out. `pool.map` has a third argument 'chunksize', which is exactly what I needed. When I set it to 1 (`pool.map(do_stuff, work, 1)`) I get the desired behavior, and the speed :)